# Mean energy expression in the isothermal-isobaric ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability

I'm dealing with the isothermal-isobaric ensemble, where the fixed parameters are temperature, pression and particle number: $T,P,N$.

I konw that the expression for the mean value of the volume is easily derived and is given by $\langle V \rangle=-\frac{1}{\beta}\frac{\partial}{\partial P}\log Z$, where $Z(T,P,N)=\int e^{-\beta(H(q,p)-PV(q,p))}\text{d}q\text{d}p$ is the partition function of this ensemble and $\beta=\frac{1}{kT}$ where $k$ is the Boltzmann constant.

**My question is if there is a simple expression even for the mean value of the energy.**

$ $

My attempt:
\begin{gather*}
\langle H \rangle=\frac{1}{Z}\int H(q,p)e^{-\beta(H(q,p)+PV(q,p))}\text{d}q\text{d}p=
\\
=\frac{1}{Z}\int (H(q,p)+PV(q,p)-PV(q,p))e^{-\beta(H(q,p)+PV(q,p))}\text{d}q\text{d}p=
\\
=\frac{1}{Z}\int (H(q,p)+PV(q,p))e^{-\beta(H(q,p)+PV(q,p))}\text{d}q\text{d}p-\frac{P}{Z}\int V(q,p)e^{-\beta(H(q,p)+PV(q,p))}\text{d}q\text{d}p=
\\
=-\frac{1}{Z}\int\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}e^{-\beta(H(q,p)-PV(q,p))}\text{d}q\text{d}p+\frac{P}{Z\beta}\int\frac{\partial}{\partial P}e^{-\beta(H(q,p)-PV(q,p))}\text{d}q\text{d}p=
\\
=-\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial\beta}+\frac{P}{Z\beta}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial P}
\end{gather*}
Am I right? Thank you!

Again, is there any nice expression for $\langle H^2 \rangle$? Reasoning as above (namely writing $H^2=H(H+PV-PV)=...$ and so on) I have found:
\begin{gather*}
\langle H^2 \rangle=\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial^2Z}{\partial\beta^2}+\frac{P^2}{Z\beta^2}\frac{\partial^2Z}{\partial P^2}-\frac{2P}{Z\beta}\frac{\partial^2Z}{\partial P\partial\beta}+\frac{2P}{Z\beta^2}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial P}
\end{gather*}

Comment: The volume $V$ does not depend on the $q$ and $p$'s.

Comment: Moreover, the partition function contains an integral over the volume.

Comment: Yes, I know that the partiton function can be written in the form: $Z(T,P,N)=\int Z(T,V,N)e^{-\beta(E+PV)}\text{d}V$, where $Z(T,V,N)$ is the canonical partition function. The volume $V(q,p)$ is simply the volume of the system that corresponds to the microscopic configuration $(q,p)$. My professor uses this convention, however, and this makes sense to me since we have to consider the average of the volume, which is not fixed here. See for example pag 5 and 6 of this pdf: http://micro.stanford.edu/~caiwei/me334/Chap9_NPT_Grand_Canonical_Ensemble_v04.pdf

Comment: In no place, in the pdf you linked, I can see $V(q,p)$. It would be a nonsense. The fact that volume is not fixed has nothing to do with its supposed dependency on $p $ and $q$. $V$ is a macrostate variable, separate from the microscopic variables.

Comment: At this wikipedia page (it is russian, but you can translate it) it is assumed that the volume depends on the microstates of the system: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8C

Comment: It is just a matter of terminology but there too there is nothing justifying the possibility of looking at $V$ as a function of position and momenta. What that page is saying is that the individual elements of the ensemble at fixed $P$ have different volumes. In this sense, they call $\hat V$ a microscopic quantity. I would prefer to call it a macroscopic but fluctuating quantity. At the end of the day, the dominant contribution to the averages, for a macroscopic number of particles, comes from macroscopic volumes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your result for $\langle H\rangle$ is correct given you know
how to calculate your $V(q,p)$. I have not checked your
result for $\langle H^2\rangle$, but the method is valid.

A few comments that might be helpful:

Your calculation
uses the classical expression for the sum (i.e. integral) over states.
The result is
valid quantum mechanically if you replace the classical state sum with the
corresponding trace over any complete set and the mathematics is more
compact. That is write
\begin{equation}
\langle H \rangle = \frac{
{\rm tr} \hat H e^{-\beta(\hat H+P\hat V)}}{
{\rm tr} e^{-\beta(\hat H+P\hat V)}}
\end{equation}
where $\hat H$ and $\hat V$ are the Hamiltonian and volume operators,
and the trace is over a complete set of states corresponding to all
possible values of the volume. The Hamiltonian you use doesn't have terms
that give matrix elements between states with different volume, so
the volume and Hamiltonian operators commute and you can take the
derivatives with result to $\beta$ and $P$ as you did classically.
Your partitiion function is
\begin{equation}
Z = {\rm tr} e^{-\beta(\hat H+P\hat V)} = e^{-\beta G}
\end{equation}
where $G$ is the Gibbs free energy. Taking your same derivatives
gives the same result quantum mechanically, and therefore also classically.

Thermodynamically the Gibbs free energy can be obtained by
Legendre transforming the energy $G = E+PV-TS$,  and
$\frac{\partial G}{\partial T} = -S$, $\frac{\partial G}{\partial P} = V$.
Thermodynamically,
$E = G+P\frac{\partial G}{\partial V}-T\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}$,
which is a check for $E = \langle H\rangle$.

As to using $V(q,p)$, I agree with GiorgioP that in the end the dominant
contribution to the averages is the macroscopic $V$. The only way that
I can see to calculate your $V(q,p)$ is to formulate the problem in the
usual way with a volume integral,
change variables from $q_i$ to $x_i = q_i/L$, with $L=V^{1/3}$
for a cubic box. Now all the volume dependence of the integrand can
be put in the exponent. In the usual case,
the $q$ and $p$ integrals are done, and the volume integral is
a product of the increasing
function like the $V^N$ from the change of variables and
the decreasing functions
of $V$ in the exponent which give the usual result of $V$
strongly peaked around
the macroscopic value. Assuming this same situation occurs for the volume
dependence and the integrand at fixed $p$ and $x$ values this peak of
the integrand as a function of $x$ and $p$ would define a $V(q,p)$.
This seems to me to be much more complicated than the usual method of
simply keeping the $V$ integral, but if it goes through for your Hamiltonian it would be
correct.